# How do you remove (or 'unstore') an element from a Z3 array?

Tags: z3

It is easy to store an element into a Z3 array. For example:

```
ArrayExpr mem = ctx.MkArrayConst("mem", ctx.MkBitVecSort(nBits), ctx.MkBitVecSort(nBits));
BitVecExpr addr = ctx.MkBV(10, nBits);
BitVecExpr value = ctx.MkBV(20, nBits);
mem = ctx.MkStore(mem, addr, value);
```

But how do you change or remove an element from such an array?

The method MkSetDel with signature "ArrayExpr MkSetDel(ArrayExpr set, Expr element)" seem to suggest that it can be (mis)used for that purpose; but sadly, it only accepts sets.

If there exists a method to iterate over the asserted elements in the array, I could populate a new array and skip the one I am changing or deleting. But I can  not find such a method.

I guess I missing something.

Comment: I don't know if the push/pop semantics of Z3 will work for you, but have you tried checking that?

Answer (score 0):

Z3 essentially supports a first-order logic with theory extensions such as array, and consequently only supports *values*, which are by definition immutable. Arrays are also values, and cannot be changed. Updating an array (at some index) yields a new array (an array value) whose elements are equal to those from the original array *except* at the index that your change affected.

See the [Z3 tutorial on array](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h26) for more details about arrays and the `store` and `select` operations.

By the way, what do you mean with "remove an element from an array"? Would that shorten the array by cutting out an element? That isn't even supported in most programming languages (where arrays are consecutive memory locations). Would it shift all subsequent elements to the front?

Comment: Remove may be a misleading verb, I was looking for a dual the store operation, an 'UnStore' or 'unread-over-write',  such that 'mem == ctx.MkStore(ctx.MkUnStore(mem, addr), addr, value)'. After a second thought, such an operations may not have a trivial semantics. I currently keep a shadow list of stored index-value pairs and rebuild the array mimicking an 'UnStore'.